# How to get the ref of a children when its a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

Im trying to create a HOC to get the `ref` of any component.

When I pass normal jsx, works well. But it doesnt work when I pass a functional component:

```
class GetRef extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderChildren = this.renderChildren.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setRef(this.ref);
  }

  renderChildren() {
    const childElement = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    return React.cloneElement(childElement, { ref: (el) => (this.ref = el) });
  }

  render() {
    return <>{this.renderChildren()}</>;
  }
}

const RefRegister = ({ children }) => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState();
  console.log({ ref });
  return <GetRef setRef={setRef}>{React.Children.only(children)}</GetRef>;
};

const Example = () => <div>example</div>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RefRegister>
        {/* <div>example</div> */} Works well in this case
        <Example /> // Throws an error passing a component :(
      </RefRegister>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hertz-fww3o?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components):

```
const Example = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>example</div>);
```

Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-proskuriakova-ywdj6